# Rails date dropdown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, haml

I'm creating a registration form for my User model, and I'm trying to put a birthdate in there. I use haml:

```
= f.date_select :dob, { start_year: 100.years.ago.year, end_year: Date.today.year, prompt: Date.today}
```

When I refresh the page in the browser I get this message:

```
undefined method `day' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x00000009db8d88>
```

What to do? I was looking at this:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: Maybe `prompt` should be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because of your prompt value. The date helper is looking for a hash of prompt values and you are passing it a Date object which the helper sees as a hash with indifferent access meaning it doesn't have a method like `your_prompt_hash.day`.

See the example on the Date helper page you linked to:

```
# Generates a date select with custom prompts.
date_select("article", "written_on", prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' })
```

What you're looking for is `:default` such as:

```
= f.date_select :dob, { start_year: 100.years.ago.year, end_year: Date.today.year, default: Date.today}
```

Or you can set this in your controller like:

```
def new
  @your_model = YourModel.new
  @your_model.dob = Date.today
end
```

Or you can set the default value for dob in your model like:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_initialize :set_defaults

 private
   def set_defaults
     self.dob ||= Date.today
   end
end
```

Either the model or controller solutions would allow you to omit the default value from the date_select call.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
= f.date_select :dob, { start_year: 100.years.ago.year, end_year: Date.today.year}, prompt: {day: Date.today} %>
```

You can use **[select_year](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year)** too in your case

```
f.select_year(Date.today, :start_year => 100.years.ago.year, :end_year => Date.today.year, :field_name => 'dob')
```